# implementing a customised string class to support fast operation on large amount of small strings

Tags: c++, string

I need to implement my own string class.

I am thinking about using `vector<char>` as the underlying data structure, but not sure if it is a good design to start with.

The aim is to to support all common string operations and to be extremly fast for large amount of small strings.

I guess string pool is the way to go, but need to decide the underlying data strucure. And I do not want to use std::string

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Use `std::string`.

Comment: @juanchopanza From the question: "_I need to implement my own string class._"

Comment: Why do you want to re-implement a new string class?

Comment: What properties and operations should your string class have? The most appropriate data structure will depend on that.

Comment: @nouney But there aren't any details of what the class should do. If OP can use `std::vector`, they might as well use `std::string`, either directly, or as a component of this new string class.

Comment: @nouney: even if you believe the OP's unsubstantiated "need" for Yet Another C++ String Class, `std::string` can still form the basis for this magical new class.  Maybe all that's needed are a few extra convenience methods (say, `is_palindrome()` or `startswith()`).  Juancho's answer is not only appropriate, it's canonical.

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Comment: It really depends on what you want this class to do.  The one using the simplest data structures would be to have an array of `char`.  `std::vector` has lots of fancy functionality that you could leverage, but if you are allowed to use that, then why not use `std::string` as the base class?  You'd get all the standard string methods, and can then define your own on top.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes taught us a nice trick to differentiate strings (e.g. semantically) using tag types: https://gist.github.com/sehe/5386754

Comment: you should use dynamic allocation (using new in a constructor) and de-allocation (using delete[] in destructor) then you should add string manipulation methods.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus **NO, you should not** do that.

Comment: Learning purposes or simply "Yet Another C++ String Class"?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Do you have a better suggestion for **my own string class** if he is not allowed to use std classes?

Comment: @MinimusHeximus And who said he is not allowed to use standard library, again? Quite the contrary, it was OP who suggested `vector<char>`

Comment: My suggestion is with this assumption. if he's allowed to use std.. there are better suggestions.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus then perhaps you shouldn't make random assumptions next time?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz it was not random. *My own string class* implies ;

Comment: @MinimusHeximus and `vector<char>` implies something completely opposite. Now it's just obvious you didn't read the question before posting.

Comment: acutally want it to support all common string operation and to be extremly fast for large amount of small strings

Comment: @hongpei Is this an exercise or you need it somewhere?

Comment: this is not an exercise or homework although it sounds like so. This is to support a in house database string manipulation.

Comment: @hongpei then you need SSO

Comment: why do you want to reinvent the wheel in hope that it would fit exactly your needs and end up with countless bugs and untested situations? as others have advised go with std::string.

Comment: To those doubting the need for a custom string class, don't be quick to judge. I once had a program that was taking an unacceptable amount of time to operate on a large number of strings. Since my strings were all constant size I was able to write my own string class with fixed storage which sped things up immensely. This was about 8 years ago so I don't remember the exact numbers but it was probably at least 5x faster.

Answer (score 2):

I *have* been in this exact situation.

That is to say, I measured the performance of my code, and identified a bottleneck in the implementation of `std::string` on my platform. Of course, once I knew *that precise bottleneck*, I could solve *that* bottleneck in my new class. I was ale to do so, because the same analysis showed which string methods I did not need.

I'm not going to tell you what I didn't need, or what I changed. The question isn't about me, after all. **You** need to profile what your program does most, and what it doesn't do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about speed, neither std::string nor std::vector will be the way to go, because they allocate their memory with `new`, which is unfortunately a slow operation (order of 200 to 300 CPU cycles on my machine). So, what you need is most likely some memory management scheme within your string class that is specially geared towards your own string processing needs.

I cannot give any more detailed advise, because I don't know your detailed needs like:

- Do your strings change? Is there any need to expand/shrink their buffer?
- Do you create your strings once to basically remain alive until the end of the process, or do you have a large constantly changing pool of strings?

The answers to these questions have a huge impact on what you can sensibly do.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion would be to write a String class where each String object includes a fixed-sized char buffer as member variable (e.g. char fixedBuffer[32]) so that in the common short-string case the class doesn't have to do any memory allocations or deallocations or pooling or whatnot.  (The cost of that is that sizeof(String) for your String class may become larger, and those extra bytes would be wasted if your String doesn't fit in the fixed-size char array...  but you mentioned that small strings are your particular use case here).

FWIW I wrote a String class that uses that technique, although its idea of a "small string" is  any string that contains 8 chars or less (including the NUL terminator byte).  That way I was able to keep the char buffer in a union along with the traditional (char *) pointer used for longer strings, and thus the sizeof(String) wasn't increased by the presence of the char array member variable.  It can be set at compile-time to use a larger inline char buffer, though, at the expense of making the object-size larger.  My implementation can be found [here](https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/muscle/util/String.h) and [here](https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/muscle/util/String.cpp); it's part of a [BSD-licensed library](https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/) I wrote.